# Spring Integration, Google Pubsub Auto ack not working

Tags: spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub

Following is an Spring IntegrationFlow i am trying to make work using Spring integration 6 and Google PubSub 1.123.  However, AUTO acknowledgment is not working reason being the routeToRecpient is one way message handle. Is routeToRecipents one-way MessageHandle or am i doing something worng. is there a way to pass on the message to main flow ?

```
public IntegrationFlow processEvent() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(Function.class, gateway -> gateway.beanName("onMessage"))
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Alert.class))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h
                        .headerFunction(POSTGRES, t -> POSTGRES.equalsIgnoreCase(store) || ALL.equalsIgnoreCase(store))
                        .headerFunction(BIGTABLE, t -> BIGTABLE.equalsIgnoreCase(store) || ALL.equalsIgnoreCase(store))
                        .headerFunction(NOSUPPORT,
                                t -> !BIGTABLE.equalsIgnoreCase(store) && !ALL.equalsIgnoreCase(store)
                                        && !POSTGRES.equalsIgnoreCase(store)))
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "Message Routed to DB store", t -> t.toString())
                
                .routeToRecipients(r -> r
                        .recipientMessageSelectorFlow(m -> m.getHeaders().get(BIGTABLE, Boolean.class),
                                c -> c.channel(postgresRouteChannel()))
                        .recipientMessageSelectorFlow(m -> m.getHeaders().get(BIGTABLE, Boolean.class),
                                c -> c.channel(bigtableRouteChannel()))
                        .recipientMessageSelectorFlow(m -> m.getHeaders().get(NOSUPPORT, Boolean.class),
                                c -> c.channel(noSupportRouteChannel())))

                .get();
```

Need a way to handle the acknowledgement to PubSub messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is that a `Function`? What do you produce from your flow? It really looks like your logic is one way and distribution. Isn't `Consumer` works for your instead?

That's probably indeed a reason why auto-ack is not happened: the `Function` waits for a reply, but you don't produce one.  We may do that as well, but need to understand what you are going to produce as a reply.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out using consumer fixed the issue.